# Compare two charcolumns without case sensivity in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, varchar, case-insensitive

I have an SQL select which have a join in a part on a column which is AAA in one table and aaA in another one. I want to join without regarding to case .but it doesnt return right answer(I want all records to be returned during this select)

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TABLE1 
   INNER JOIN TABLE2
      ON lower(TABLE1.Col1) = lower(TABLE2.Col2);
```

I added **COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS** after select but no correct answer.
I set the collation of both columns to deafult database collation , but no answer.

help please

Comment: Can you show some sample data for both column? cause applying `LOWER()` function on both column actually should work.

Comment: @Rahul : forexp: 'METRO' in TABLE1 should match 'Metro' in TABLE2. I tested the Upper function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you're showing doesn't return the rows you're expecting, then the problem is something besides letter case. There are either unprintable or other characters in the strings, or you're looking at the wrong tables, or some other issue. Using `lower` or `COLLATE` with a case-insensitive collation (containing "CI") will both work. If they're not working, it's something else.

Comment: I guessed that, and ran the query in another system, but with the same database , maybe its because of some setting in instanse of SQLServer, is it possible?

Comment: youre right, my problem was the SQL instance Setting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. The CI is CaseIncensative.

```
select *
from t1
join t2 ON t1.Col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = t2.Col2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: You only need one COLLATE clause, not two. The single COLLATE after either expression on one side of the equals sign will govern the comparison.